# Excel VBA Setting Item as the Default for the Class Property Get and Let

Tags: excel, vba, class, get, let

I created this class to experiment with it. My goal is to see if I can read/write data in this format:

```
x = AppInventory(r,c): AppInventory(r,c) = x
x = AppInventory("A1"): AppInventory("A1") = x
x = AppInventory(cellRange): AppInventory(cell(cellRange) = x
```

This works when adding `.Item: x = AppInventory.Item(r,c)`

But I am hoping to eliminate the `.Item()`, is this possible to default to .Item?

Has anyone ever defaulted Item so you don't have to type it? Or is there another easier way? I tried using Get/Let and Property in the main code, that did not work because the r,c vs string text proves to be a problem because sometimes I am using 1 parameter and other times 2.

Any ideas is appreciated. Thanks.

Class Name: AppInventory

```
    Private ws As Worksheet
    Private targetCell As Range
        
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AppInventory")
    End Sub
    
    Public Property Get Item(Index1 As Variant, Optional Index2 As Variant) As Variant
        Set targetCell = GetTargetCell(Index1, Index2)
        Item = targetCell.Value
    End Property
        
    Public Property Let Item(Index1 As Variant, Optional Index2 As Variant, ByVal Value As Variant)
        Set targetCell = GetTargetCell(Index1, Index2)
        targetCell.Value = Value
    End Property
        
    Private Function GetTargetCell(Index1 As Variant, Optional Index2 As Variant) As Range
        Select Case VarType(Index1)
            Case vbInteger, vbLong ' Numeric, likely row number
                Set GetTargetCell = ws.Cells(Index1, Index2)
            Case vbString ' String, like "A1"
                Set GetTargetCell = ws.Range(Index1)
            Case vbObject ' Range object
                Set GetTargetCell = ws.Range(Index1.Address)
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Invalid input"
        End Select
    End Function
```

So far my ideas failed:

```
Public Default Property Get Item(Index1 As Variant, Optional Index2 As Variant) As Variant
Default Public Property Get Item(Index1 As Variant, Optional Index2 As Variant) As Variant
```

I even tried exporting the class and adding `Attribute Item.VB UserMemID = 0` just after the `Get Item()` and then importing it back in to see if that would work. I think I got it working once, but when I modified the class with simple comments I think it went away and I can't get that working again.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx

Comment: I researched more about the Attribute Item option and found this: [link](https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/694992-how-declare-default-property-class-module)

The problem I have is the attribute disappears when importing; and when I export to see if it's there, it's not, it gets blown away on the import.

Comment: `Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0` worked fine for me and was still present after exporting the class module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provide look like you are not creating an instance of your class.

```
x = AppInventory(r,c): AppInventory(r,c) = x
x = AppInventory("A1"): AppInventory("A1") = x
x = AppInventory(cellRng): AppInventory(cell(rnd) = x
```

The code above will not work unless you have AppInventory set as a PredeclaredId.

Try the following

```
Dim MyInv as AppInventory
Set myInv = new AppInventory
myInv.Item(r,c)=x
```

The .Item can be eliminated if you set Item to be the default member.

A number of class attributes are not available from within VBA meaning you ave to export the code , set the attribute and then reimport.

A much easier way to proceed is to install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA.  This addin allows you to set attibutes by the use of annotations prefixed with '@

```
'\@DefaultMember
Public Property Get Item(Index1 As Variant, Optional Index2 As Variant) As Variant
        Set targetCell = GetTargetCell(Index1, Index2)
        Item = targetCell.Value
    End Property
        
    Public Property Let Item(Index1 As Variant, Optional Index2 As Variant, ByVal Value As Variant)
        Set targetCell = GetTargetCell(Index1, Index2)
        targetCell.Value = Value
    End Property
```

You need to run the Rubberduck parse to get the attibutes updated.

Good luck

Comment: I will look into the Rubberduck addin, thanks for advising on that.

Sorry for not including my main code, I actually do have the predeclarations as you mentioned. In fact, to make debugging easier, I separated the New out and set them up as Dim and Set separately.

Comment: That's the kind of response that make really wonder why I bother trying to help folks on SO.

Comment: It worked! I figured out my mistake, I placed a comment before the Attribute Item.VB_UserMemID = 0

I was able to make this work for both my Get and Let, I just needed to add that attribute line as the first line of code for both my Get and Let Property() sections of code.

Thanks freeflow for the Rubberduck suggestion and BigBen for confirming that the Attribute code worked for you. This helped me to believe it could work and just press on. Commenting is bad in this case.

Comment: Anyone know of a source where I can learn more about the class attributes that are not available within VBA? I want to learn more on this.  As always, thanks for the help.

Comment: You could start here https://rubberduckvba.blog/tag/attributes/

Comment: Somewhat related, because I'd be adding to this code. Is there a way to add the ability to expand this to support a select? e.g.  AppInventory("A1").select

Comment: What do you mean by select?  Do you want the item method to also select the range.  If so would that be on a Get or Set.  It would make your code remarkably unclear and riddled with side effect so I wouldn't recommend it.